# NameError: uninitialized constant and LoadError: Unable to autoload constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, eager-loading, nameerror

After upgrade to Rails 5.0.1, I started getting intermittent `NameError: uninitialized constant Payments::EventHandlers` errors.
Here is how my class is defined:

Code:

```
# app/managers/finance/payments/event_handlers/customer.rb
module Finance
  module Payments
    module EventHandlers
      class Customer < Finance::Payments::BaseStripeEventHandler
        # various methods
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
# app/managers/finance/payments/base_stripe_event_handler.rb
module Finance
  module Payments
    class BaseStripeEventHandler < Finance::BaseStripeEventHandler
      # various methods
    end
  end
end
```

```
# app/managers/finance/base_stripe_event_handler.rb
module Finance
  class BaseStripeEventHandler
    # various methods
  end
end
```

I was able to reproduce this error on Rails console as below:

```
Loading staging environment (Rails 5.0.1)
2.4.6 :001 > Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Customer
 => Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Customer
2.4.6 :002 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true
2.4.6 :003 > Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Customer
NameError: uninitialized constant Finance
```

So following https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-is-disabled-after-booting-in-the-production-environment, I modified my `config/application.rb` file as below:

```
    config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.enable_dependency_loading = true
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

After these changes, I started getting `LoadError: Unable to autoload constant`:

```
Loading staging environment (Rails 5.0.1)
2.4.6 :001 > Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Customer
 => Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Customer
2.4.6 :002 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true
2.4.6 :003 > Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Customer
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Customer, expected .../app/managers/finance/payments/event_handlers/customer.rb to define it
```

I am not clear if it is a directory structure issue or the way `customer` class is defined. Can someone provide guidance on how to fix it?

Thanks.

**Edits**
I removed `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` from `config/application.rb` and it is still giving same results.
Appreciate any help on this!

**Edits 2 (implement suggestion by Roman Alekseiev )**

As suggested by Roman Alekseiev, I added below:

```
# app/managers/finance.rb
module Finance; end
```

```
# app/managers/finance/payments.rb
module Finance
  module Payments
  end
end
```

```
# app/managers/finance/payments/event_handlers.rb
module Finance
  module Payments
    module EventHandlers
    end
  end
end
```

After these changes, I think I have made some progress as above NameError is not occurring in the console anymore after `reload!`.

But when my worker runs this job, it is still returning this NameError:
Worker is executing below code:

```
scope = "Payments" # conditionally assigned
handler_class = "Invoice" # again, conditionally assigned
constant_name = "::Finance::#{scope}::EventHandlers::#{handler_class[:handler]}" # in this case ::Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::Invoice
Object.const_get(constant_name)
```

Last statement above returns `NameError: uninitialized constant Payments::EventHandlers`

```
# app/managers/finance/payments/event_handlers/invoice.rb
module Finance
  module Payments
    module EventHandlers
      class Invoice < Finance::Payments::BaseStripeEventHandler
        # various methods
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Code seems fine. Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev It is app/managers/finance/payments/event_handlers/customer.rb

Comment: Can someone provide some direction on this issue? thank you.

Comment: Hi All, Can you please help on this?

Comment: how is this related with `config.root/lib` if your code is under `managers` directory?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev You are right! It isn't. To begin with, I had both autoload_paths and eager_load_paths. I just was to indicate that I have removed autoload_paths since I had mentioned it in my original question; and it is no longer needed in Rails 5.

Comment: Accordingly to rails docs all under `app` directory has to be loaded automatic. 
Autoload paths automatically pick any custom directories under `app`. For example, if your application has `app/presenters`, or `app/services`, etc., they are added to autoload paths. So it seems it is not related with autoload.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am not sure why this object is not accessible. Can you please suggest what I may be missing here? Looks like very fundamental issue in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but as a suggestion what if you add this file and code to your structure.
Under `app/managers` directory create file `finance.rb` with code below

```rb
module Finance; end
```

Under `app/managers/finance` create file `payments.rb` with code below

```rb
module Finance
  module Payments
  end
end
```

Under `app/managers/finance/payments` create file (if not exist) `event_handlers.rb` with code

```rb
module Finance
  module Payments
    module EventHandlers
    end
  end
end
```

I had similar problem, this approach helped, hope it will help you also

Answer (score 0):

This actually depends upon your folder structure. Not sure where you want your base_event_handler.rb file to be ? Do you want to keep it inside **event_handlers** folder or inside **payments** folder ?

This should be the structure if you want the **base_event_handler.rb** file to be inside **event_handlers** folder :

```
module Finance
  module Payments
    module EventHandlers
      class Customer < Finance::Payments::EventHandlers::BaseEventHandler
        def method1
          puts "Hello there ---"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

NOTE: Do define your base_event_handler.rb file too, else you will be getting NameError for not defining :

```
module Finance
  module Payments
    module EventHandlers
      class BaseEventHandler
        def methodE
          puts "This base event"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have edited question to add more details about BaseStripeEventHandler